# Can there be instantaneous change in force (friction)?

Tags: forces, friction

When an object is moving on a rough surface with only frictional force acting on it, there will be some kinetic friction on it which is constant until object comes to rest. The moment it stops, frictional force on it will be zero. Can force change instantaneously?

Comment: See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144748/157583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can force change instantaneously?

As already pointed out force cannot change instantaneously. To put it another velocity cannot change instantaneously (in zero time) as that would imply the application of an infinite force.

If I understand you correctly, the reason you are asking this question is because of the assumption that kinetic friction is constant throughout and does not depend on the velocity. This is what Charles Coulomb discovered nearly 300 years ago. But experiments since have shown that the law is only approximately valid. References to some of these experiments can be found in the following link:

https://hal-ens-lyon.archives-ouvertes.fr/ensl-00589509/document

You said in the beginning that only friction force is acting on the object. I interpret that to mean that whatever force got the object going in the first place is no longer being applied and thus the object is slowing down strictly due to the opposing kinetic friction force which is doing negative work on the object taking its kinetic energy and converting it into heat, according to the work energy theorem. When the object stops, there are no external forces being applied to it. If my assumption is incorrect, please let me know.

Since the kinetic friction force only exists in opposition to relative motion at the surface, in my view at some point as the velocity of object approaches zero, the kinetic friction force also approaches zero, such that both equal zero when the object stops.

I make no claim to be an expert on friction. Consequently I welcome any other alternative arguments or explanations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand here is the exact meaning of the word 'Kinetic' friction. This frictional force always acts on an object as long as it's in contact with the surface due to roughness in the surface. It manifests in two forms Kinetic frictional force and static frictional force. As long as the object is moving, the frictional force will retard the object and eventually it will come to a complete stop. When the object is at rest, what acts on the object is static friction. So the force does not instantaneously become zero. The kinetic frictional force retards the object and once it stops, the static frictional force still acts on the object as long as it's in contact with the surface.

Comment: Static friction only exists in opposition to a force on an object to resist impending motion.  Kinetic friction only exists when there is relative motion between the surfaces. In this case there are no forces acting on the object except kinetic friction. When the object stops, there is no static friction force.

Comment: When an object comes to rest, no static frictional force exists. When you initially apply a force, the static friction balances the external force. The object starts to move the moment the external force dominates the static friction. But if static friction exist when the external force is removed, then the object would move forever without any external energy input, and this is not posible.

Answer (score 0):

Instantaneous change in force is never possible. Assume that you stopped the object instantaneously, i.e., in an infinitesimal duration of time. In that case, the acceleration would be infinite:
$$|a|=\lim_{dt\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{dv}{dt}\right)\rightarrow \infty$$
But acceleration cannot be infinite.
In reality, the force gradually changes over a very short (though finite) duration of time.

Comment: I agree with what you say, but the OP is, I believe, trying to square the assumption that the kinetic friction force is constant (independent of velocity) but is  then zero when the motion stops and does that mean the kinetic friction force goes to zero instantaneously. If not, then how does it transition to zero.

Comment: @BobD When the object is stopped, the force gradually decreases over a very short duration to zero. Two parts of this transient phase: (1) kinetic friction acts on the object regardless of the magnitude of the force while the object comes to rest. (2) After the object comes to rest, the external force is still in the decreasing phase and there is no kinetic friction but static friction acts for the duration while the external force decreases to zero.

Comment: The OP states in the first sentence "only friction force acting on it" so its velocity is obviously decreasing because of the friction force. Your comment makes sense if there were an equal external force pushing against the friction force so that the object initially moves at constant velocity and then that external force  is gradually reduced to bring the object to as stop. Then the external force is opposed by static friction. But as I read it, that's not what's happening here.